# AllowAutoRedirect does not work with .NET 4.8 but with .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net

We are testing with redirects and found out that there is a difference between .NET 4.8 and .NET 6. Our test server, lets name it https://testserver-one.foo should throw a HTTP 308 - Permanent Redirect and redirect to https://testserver-two.foo

Within our WPF app with .NET 4.8 we tried two ways to check for the redirect.

First one:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://testserver-one.foo");
request.ContentType = "text/html";
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

try
{
    var response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}
```

Second one:

```
try
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = true
    };

    var client = new HttpClient(handler);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://testserver-one.foo");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}
```

In both cases, despite the AllowAutoRedirect = true, an exception is thrown, status ProtocolError.

If we use the same code samples within a WPF app with .NET 6 the redirect is handled gracefully, after the 308 the redirect is handled and after that we get a 200.

Can anybody tell me what our problem is and what can we do that the redirect is handled correct with .NET 4.8?

Comment: Although I believe the value should be the same for both versions, did you try setting the "MaxAutomaticRedirections" on the HttpClientHandler to a higher value?

Comment: The default HTTP Headers are probably different.  For example User-Agent and Content Type.  You have to add/modify headers so they are the same.  You can use a sniffer and compare the two request to see differences.

Comment: I have raised "MaxAutomaticRedirections" to 10, unfortunately the result stays the same.

Comment: The default HTTP Headers are equal, i can see no difference between .NET 4.8 and .NET 6

Comment: Maybe TLS? Since you have one working and one not working, the easiest way to see the difference is with Wireshark.

Comment: After looking into source code of .NET 4.8 (HttpWebRequest.cs) it seems that HTTP error 308 is not handled in combination with AllowAutoRedirect. Only 300, 301, 302, 303 and 307 are automatically redirected if flag is set to true.